# fetching user name

Tags: users

how to fetch user name and this types of information's as a php variable, which can be added as PHP code in block. 
As a example, a Welcome message like,

```
Hi, $data['user'] Welcome to my site
```

It's output should like this:

```
Hi, user name Welcome to my site
```

above code is not working but i think you understand what i want to do. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The username is attached to the global `$user` object so you can get it like this:

```
global $user;
$username = $user->name;
```

And then output it like this:

```
print 'Hi, ' . $username . ' Welcome to my site';
```

Comment: something going wrong, because every time i add this code in a block, nothing appear it shows only this code .. so exactly what i should write in a block?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to put PHP code into the body of a custom block? You'll need to enable the PHP filter module and choose that as the input format for the block body

Comment: from where i can enable  PHP code? Thanks

Comment: from module (core module)

Comment: but i can not fetch users profile picture. How to fetch users profile picture?

Comment: i have tried this but it shows user number `$userphoto = $user->picture;`